# How would one store a Dictionary in a SQLServer User-Defined Type?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012

Context: SQLServer2012

On one of Microsoft's [CLR User-Defined Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120%28SQL.100%29.aspx) pages, it says (in part)

> Beginning with SQL Server 2005, you can use user-defined types (UDTs) to extend the scalar type system of the server, enabling storage of CLR objects in a SQL Server database.

Does this mean that I could turn a Dictionary into an UDT? If so, how? If not, why not?

Assuming I don't run into issues with System.Core and all that, I'm hoping that perhaps I can do something useful with [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this for JSON parsing:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>("{'some':['deeply',{'nested':'json record'}]});
```

Comment: If I was even thinking about this, I would need a very good reason not to be thinking about just having a table storing keys and values in two columns (and other columns if multiple "dictionaries" are required). Do you have strong reasons for not choosing to go down that route?

Comment: I've been climbing the walls of the JSON-in-SQLServer castle all this week. Right now, I'm about ready to try almost anything. The one thing I'm not ready to do is make System.Core 'available'.

Comment: Oh, and the JSON I'm intending to read (just by way of frightening you even more) is from Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Damien_The_Unbeliever. the easy, straight-forward, and probably best way is a 2 column table, key and value.

However, there is another option, and that is to use an XML Column and just store your serialized dictionary there. Note that this means that if you do want to change or the data using SQL, your DML statements are going to be highly complex and inefficient comparing with the simple 2 columns table approach.